# Applications of PDEs in many variables

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

One reason that solving systems of partial differential equations is so important is the many applications of PDEs in science and engineering (eg. the heat equation, the wave equation, etc.). Often these use numerical methods. However, most of these applications that I am aware of involve systems of PDEs in only a few variables, often corresponding to physical dimensions and/or time.

What are some important applications of systems of PDEs in many variables, or even when the number of variables is growing as a parameter of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ian Mitchell's [A Toolbox of Level Set Methods](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mitchell/ToolboxLS/):

> ... a software package for solving time-dependent [Hamilton-Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)
>   partial differential equations (PDEs) in the MATLAB programming
>   environment. Level set methods are often used for simulation of
>   **dynamic implicit surfaces** in graphics,  fluid and combustion
>   simulation, image processing, and computer vision. Hamilton-Jacobi and
>   related PDEs arise in fields such as control, robotics, differential
>   games, dynamic programming, mesh generation, stochastic differential
>   equations,  financial mathematics, and verification. The algorithms in
>   the toolbox can be used in any number of dimensions, although
>   computational cost and visualization difficulty make **dimensions four
>   and higher** a challenge.

Comment: This is a nice answer - I'm now starting a bounty in the hope of getting more suggestions.